# send email into CakePHP by jqueryui

Tags: jquery, email, cakephp-2.0

I need to send email for administrator, and also to user, after user fill jqueryui form.
So I have view.ctp jqueryui dialog form:

```
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="name">Имя</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>


<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
</div>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div> 
    </main> 
    <!--*******FOOTER********-->
    <footer>
        <div id="footer">
            <?php // debug($product);      ?>
            <?php // "<p>" . debug($tags) . "</p>" ?>   
            <?php // "<p>" . debug($tags_values) . "</p>" ?>   
        </div>
    </footer>
     <script>
  $(function() {
    var name = $( "#name" ),
      email = $( "#email" ),
      password = $( "#password" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

          bValid = bValid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
          bValid = bValid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );

          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter." );
          // From jquery.validate.js (by joern), contributed by Scott Gonzalez: http://projects.scottsplayground.com/email_address_validation/
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( email, /^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
          bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );

          if ( bValid ) {
            $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
              "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
              "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
            "</tr>" );
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    $( "#create-user" )
      .button()
      .click(function() {
        $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
      });
  });
  </script>
```

Then when i click create account or something else - I need to send this data for user email.
The question is:
How to retrieve data in controller function from jqueryui form (I'm new in jquery) and also how to send this data by email???

Comment: presumably your jquery form will create a HTTP request, you can view it using chrome debugging tools.

Comment: I'm new in this, so I can't imagine how to use javascript debugger. I just know that i need retrieve data from input's send it to controller and in controller make script that send this data into email. I can't find how to do this

Comment: Have you tried looking at $this->request->data on the controller?

Comment: I have tried debug($this->request->data());
But it still null after filling form
May be I'm wrong to do something. It showing nothing, it empty when i trying debug like this debug($this->request->data());

Answer (score 2):

You need a server-side (PHP) script that will send out the e-mails for you. Then what you need to do is to make an ajax call once the form has been validated. For example you can include the ajax call as follows:

```
......
if ( bValid ) {
   $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
   "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
   "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
   "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
   "</tr>" );
   $( this ).dialog( "close" );
   $.post
   (
      './path-to-php-email-sender.php',
      { name: name.val(), email: email.val(), password: password.val() },
      function( data ) {
         alert( 'EmailSender said: ' + data );
      },'text'
   );
}
......
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer, but i think my level is not enough to undestand for now. But of course, thanks.

Comment: How can I be any more help?

Comment: Can you show me, how to retrieve data from this jquery form in controller. How it connects between controller and view. 
I'm trying to understand how can i get this data, but I'm wrong( What i need to study? Or may be you can help me something.
I know that from html form it is $this->request->data()

Comment: How would you normally make an ajax call? If I can have a clue as to how you do it in your environment, I'd be happy to make a suggestion.

Comment: Try var_dump($this->request-data), this is a variable not a function. this jquery call example is good. The php path in cakephp is wiuld be "/controller/action", in your controller you will get the email in this variable: $this->request->data['email']